# Deploy 'create react app' on HTTP not on HTTPS

Tags: reactjs, http, https, deployment

I need to deploy a simple react app just for showcase purposes. But there is a problem when I'm trying to host it on Netlify, Vercel, Firebase and I can't use heroku. I'm getting this.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ip-tracker-b72ffu8s0.vercel.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=3a79079d875...'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I would like to use https://api.ipstack.com/check instead of http://api.ipstack.com/check
but free plan do not allow me to use https.

The question is where I can deploy react-app on http? I don't care about safe connections. I just want to deploy as a demo.